# RFC3339 time parsing in golang

Tags: parsing, go, time, unix-timestamp, rfc3339

I'm pulling a timestamp from a datebase, it is using RFC3339 format but the timezone is missing. So when I try to compare the timestamps it will be off. How do I change dbtime to be Eastern time?

```
// time format
const
(
    RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
)

//now time
now := time.Now()
nowtime := now.Unix()

fmt.Println("Nowtime:", nowtime)
fmt.Println("Now:", now)

//time in db
fmt.Println("Dbtime string:", dbtime)
udbtime, err := time.Parse.EST(RFC3339,dbtime)
fmt.Println("RFC3339: " + RFC3339)
fmt.Println("dbtime parsed", udbtime)
fmt.Println("dbtime parsed unixtime", udbtime.Unix())
```

My output is

```
Nowtime: 1466443640
Now: 2016-06-20 13:27:20.963232824 -0400 EDT
Dbtime string: 2016-06-20T12:41:45.14Z
RFC3339: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
dbtime parsed 2016-06-20 12:41:45.14 +0000 UTC
dbtime parsed unixtime 1466426505
```

Comment: Give an example of the dbtime you're parsing.

Comment: The timezone isn't missing, the time `2016-06-20T12:41:45.14Z` is UTC.

Comment: Sorry the original timestamp. is 2016-06-20T12:41:45.14Z but its actually in EDT.

Comment: So you want to change the timezone?

Comment: `2016-06-20T12:41:45.14Z` can't be EDT, because the trailing `Z` specifies UTC, so you need to fix the times yourself.

Comment: If dbtime is correct for a UTC timestamp. Then the timestamp in the database is incorrect. I do not want to convert the time to UTC, I want the time to remain the same and only switch the timezone.

Comment: in your `find Query ` what is the output format of your time Hope it will be in ISO || UTC

Answer (score 4):

you can try go-carbon，a simple，semantic and developer-fridendly golang package for datetime

```golang
carbon.Parse("2020-12-31").ToRfc3339String() 
//  output
2020-12-31T00:00:00+08:00
```

https://github.com/golang-module/carbon

Answer (score 3):

You could parse the timestamps using the defined `time.RFC3339` like you've shown, and adjust them after the fact by adding the UTC offset so that they are correct in UTC.

```
udbtime = udbtime.Add(4*time.Hour)
```

This however requires that you check whether each time falls in EST or EDT to add the correct offset, unless you can assume they are all EDT.

A better way would be to use your own time format without a specific TZ offset (the Z isn't part of the time specification for parsing), and parse it with [`time.ParseInLocation`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation).

This way you can account for the correct offset depending on whether the time would have been in EST or EDT.

https://play.golang.org/p/IrUnTwvlkk

```
RFC3339local := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z"

loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

ts1 := "2016-06-20T12:41:45.14Z"
t1, _ := time.ParseInLocation(RFC3339local, ts1, loc)
fmt.Println(t1)
// prints: 2016-06-20 12:41:45.14 -0400 EDT

ts2 := "2016-01-20T12:41:45.14Z"
t2, _ = time.ParseInLocation(RFC3339local, ts2, loc)
fmt.Println(t2)
// prints: 2016-01-20 12:41:45.14 -0500 EST
```